# How do I pass an array to an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

I have an array  which I want pass to an OpenCL kernel. Part of my code is

```
cl_mem arr_cl;
unsigned int arr[4] = { 0 };

arr_cl = clCreateBuffer(ocl.context, CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, 4*sizeof(unsigned int), NULL, &status);

arr = (unsigned int*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(ocl.command_queue, arr_cl, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ | CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, 4*sizeof(unsigned int), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

status |= clSetKernelArg(ocl.kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &(arr_cl));
```

The above code compiles but crashes during run time. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

I am using OpenCL 2.0.

Comment: kernel argument has index=1. If you have only one kernel parameter, shouldn't it be 0? Also can you try with array of at least 64 elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html

> CL_MAP_READ or CL_MAP_WRITE and CL_MAP_WRITE_INVALIDATE_REGION are
>   mutually exclusive.

you should only  read or only write within a mapping if opencl version >=1.2.

Also when changing alloc_host_ptr to use_host_ptr, the array should be aligned to `CL_DEVICE_MEM_BASE_ADDR_ALIGN` value/query.